# form special character validation

Tags: php, html

I want to validate the input of a user so only letters/number and whitespace is allowed. I found a few examples on google and this is what I made out of it. For me this code is logic and should work but whenever I put a special character inside the form and after that press the submit button it wont show the error.

Does anyone know what I missed here or what I did wrong?

```
<?php
$Input1 = "";
$Input1Err = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if(empty($_POST["Input1"])){
    $Input1Err = "Enter something.";
  }else{
    $Input1 = test_input($_POST["Input1"]);
    if(!preg_match("/[^a-z0-9 _]+$/i", $Input1)){
      $Input1Err = "Only letters and space is allowed.";
    }
  }

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>
```

and here is the html code i use:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="POST">
<p>Enter your name <input type="text" required name="Input1" placeholder="Enter here.."></p> 
        <span class="error">*<?php echo $Input1Err;?></span>
```

Comment: can you share in sandbox

Comment: @deepakmurthy The PHP code won't work in a sandbox or jsfiddle for example

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['name'] != "") 
    { 
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $pattern = "/[^a-z0-9 _]+$/i";
        $result = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(preg_match($pattern, $name)));
        echo $name;
     } else {
         echo "Please enter something.";
     }

?>
```

HTML Form :

```
<form method="post" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="name" required="">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular Expression to allow only letters numbers and space
`^[a-z0-9 .\-]+$`

Also there is one closing parenthesis missing in if else condition

```
  $Input1 = "";
  $Input1Err = "";

  if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
  {
      if(empty($_POST["Input1"]))
      {
        $Input1Err = "Enter something.";
      }
      else
      {
        $Input1 = test_input($_POST["Input1"]);
        if(!preg_match('/^[a-z0-9 .\-]+$/i', $Input1))
        {
          $Input1Err = "Only letters and space is allowed.";
        }
      }
}
```